# Why is explorers shows different difficulty values?

Tags: block, difficulty, blockchain-explorer

Just take a random block for example, for block 506068, [blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info/block/00000000000000000023fe1ff94fb0d9b0b380f1f82c86b1874e0dc49c3e04d5) shows difficulty as `2,603,077,300,218.59`, while [blockcypher](https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/block/00000000000000000023fe1ff94fb0d9b0b380f1f82c86b1874e0dc49c3e04d5/) shows `392,962,374`, do the explorers use a different way to calculate them, why are they different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blockcypher is not showing difficulty but difficulty target. You can see blockchain.info also show this under 'bits'.

Comment: Read more: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Difficulty#What_is_the_formula_for_difficulty.3F